# How to model the relationship between two classes that are linked with the same attribute in UML Class Diagrams?

Tags: oop, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I have the two following classes that are linked only through a common attribute:

[image: Two classes linked only through a common attribute]

How to model the relationship between these classes, knowing that `testID` in `ErrorMessage` and `id` in `Test` are the same (meaning they represent the same value)

What UML-relationship best describes this case?

Comment: The notation of your attributes is wrong.  It should be `[name]: [type]` so `index: int` and not `int index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Test::id` is an attribute that uniquely identifies a `Test`, the relationship would be an association with the multiplicity `1` on the side of `Test` (i.e. each ErrorMessage instance is associated with one Test). As nothing prevents several different `ErrorMessage` instances to refer to the same `TestId`, the multiplicity would be `*` on the side `ErrorMessage`. Note that you could add the property modifier `{id}` after the `id` attribute to clarify that the attribute is part of the identifier for the class.

Now it seems that the `ErrorMessage` lifecycle is related to the `Test` instance: to create an `ErrorMessage`, you need to have the `id`.  Conversely,  as the id is not optional (multiplicity 0..1), we can assume that it cannot exist without a Test instance.  You may then use a composite aggregation, putting a black diamond on the side of test.

This being said, usually when designing classes, the attributes needed to implement associations are not shown. This avoids ambiguities, such as: is this int an additional attribute on top of the documented association or is it just its implementation? (you know, but not other readers). Alternatively, when modelling a comprehensive database schema ("physical model") often some [specialized UML profiles](https://agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html#Keys) are used, with stereotypes that help to clarify primary and foreign keys.

Comment: I guess it would be ore meaningful to use the object rather than the stored integer inside.

Comment: @qwerty_so indeed, I had this in mind but somehow forgot to conclude. I'll edit later today

Comment: @Christophe : 
"This being said, usually when designing classes, the attributes needed to implement associations are not shown" 

should i remove the "id" from Test and by extension "SuiteID" from ErrorMessage as they are represented by the Association ?

Comment: @noob the practice would be to keep Test::id because it is the unique identifier of Test. You can by the way add `{id}` behind it to clarify this. It is really an attribute of Test regardless any association. You would remove testId (or now suiteId), because its only use is to implement an association